# Google Script can't call Twitter API when using onEdit()

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script which will pull data from twitter's API each time I edit a cell.  The demo code I currently have looks like this:

```
var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Candidates");

function onEdit(e){
  var rng = e.range;

  // Check to make sure it is a single cell in specific column that was edited
  if(rng.getColumn() == 1 && rng.getNumRows() == 1 && rng.getNumColumns() == 1){
    callTwitter(rng.getRow());
  }
}

/* --- ---------------------- --- */
/* --- Compare with core list --- */
/* --- ---------------------- --- */
function callTwitter(cRow){
  var cRow           = 2; // placeholder for testing
  var twitterService = getTwitterService();
  var response       = JSON.parse(twitterService.fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=' + sheet.getRange(cRow, 1, 1, 1).getValue()));

  sheet.getRange(cRow,2,1,1).setValue(response[0].screen_name);
}
```

**What I've checked**

- I have confirmed that onEdit() gets called when I edit a cell and it does pass through the variable to the callTwitter() function.
- Running the callTwitter() function on its own returns the desired result (*pulls username from column A, queries twitter API and returns display name in column B*).

**The issue**

The callTwitter() function always fails when I call it via the onEdit call.  It stops right before the following line of code.

```
var response       = JSON.parse(twitterService.fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=' + sheet.getRange(cRow, 1, 1, 1).getValue()));
```

My current assumption is that the onEdit call is somehow clashing with the API call, but I can't seem to find out why or how to solve it.

--

I have been trying to debug this for hours now and any help or direction on where to look would be very helpful.

Code not included here is the Twitter OAuth which I copied from Google's example https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple triggers like onEdit won't work in this scenario. According to the documentation,

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email
>   because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger
>   can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

You must use an installable trigger.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Create the fuction that you need to execute on edit, go Edit -> Current project's triggers, and select 'From spreadsheet'-> 'On edit.